# Steps to move an ubuntu 14.04 server install disk (damaged) with lvm to a new disk on the same system

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

Need some clarification on how to move the following :
I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server install with LVM and its disk was failing. I have managed to clone the disk without any errors to a new disk of same capacity (i.e 1 TB ) using GNU ddrescue. I have checked the disk imaged and the data is there and no problems accessing it. Now I would like to put the new cloned disk back into the same system.

Will I have to do anything further to put the new disk on the same system and boot off it ?

I am aware that I may need to change fstab entries only, is there anything else I need to change on the new disk to boot correctly without any errors ?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, or it is too broad. If you cloned the whole disk (i.e., not a single partition) then everything is exactly as it was before. As if nothing ever happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it myself.

Once you clone your failed disk to another disk, in case of lvm partitions there is no need of changing the UUID of the disk in /etc/fstab.

Therefore you can just clone the disk and directly boot off it on the new server. Thats it !